# применение .each к несколько раз вложенным элементам

Tags: jquery

как сделать перебор элементов методом .each,  если они несколько раз вложены?

у меня получилось

```
let id = 0;
$( event.target ).parent().parent().children().children().each( function (index) {
$( '<img>', {
                src: $( this ).attr( 'src' )
            } ).css( 'height', '200px' ).appendTo( $( "#owl-item-" + id ) );
            id++;
        } );
```

можно сделать перебор img элементов без применения .parent.children?

html

```
<div class="variant-of-solution-list" id="office-lightning-list" >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-0" ><img src="/site/img/0.jpg" /></div >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-1" ><img src="/site/img/1.jpg" /></div >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-2" ><img src="/site/img/2.jpg" /></div >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-3" ><img src="/site/img/3.jpg" /></div >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-4" ><img src="/site/img/4.jpg" /></div >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-5" ><img src="/site/img/5.jpg" /></div >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-6" ><img src="/site/img/6.jpg" /></div >
    </div >
</div >
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('[id^="office-lightning-list-"]').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="variant-of-solution-list" id="office-lightning-list" >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-0" ><img src="/site/img/0.jpg" /></div >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-1" ><img src="/site/img/1.jpg" /></div >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-2" ><img src="/site/img/2.jpg" /></div >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-3" ><img src="/site/img/3.jpg" /></div >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-4" ><img src="/site/img/4.jpg" /></div >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-5" ><img src="/site/img/5.jpg" /></div >
        <div id="office-lightning-list-6" ><img src="/site/img/6.jpg" /></div >
    </div >
</div >
```

Comment: спасибо. да это работает, но я забыл указать, что скрипт начинается с $( '.variant-of-solution-list img' ).on( 'click', function (event) {. поэтому мы заранее не знаем, что выберет пользователь